# Change Clang formatting for {} and access modifers

Tags: c++, clang-format

In VsCode I would like to change my Clang formatting to :

```
class Test {
    public:
        Test() : tmp(0)
        {
            if (0 == 0) {
                std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        ~Test();

    protected:
    private:
        int tmp;
};
```

But currently I got :

```
class Test {
   public:
    Test() : tmp(0) {
        if (0 == 0) {
            std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    ~Test();

   protected:
   private:
    int tmp;
};
```

My CLang settings :

{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4 }

Comment: Start with the clang-format docs: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 1):

### About the brace breaking style

The brace you want to break is after a function, so you would want to add this to *Clang* setting:

```yaml
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping: 
  AfterFunction: true
```

You can find other `BraceWrapping` options in the [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

### About the modifiers indentation

At present, *Clang* provides only an option to adjust modifiers indentation - `AccessModifierOffset`. This option will offset in or out from the `IndentWidth` you set. It is not currently possible to make modifier indentation standard. Fortunately, it is currently being discussed and reviewed [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D22505).

You can set this to make it less annoying:

```yaml
AccessModifierOffset: 0
```

Here is what you get if you set all above options:

```cpp
class Test {
    public:
    Test() : tmp(0)
    {
        if (0 == 0) {
            std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    ~Test();

    protected:
    private:
    int tmp;
};
```